# /bin/sh: 1: cc: not found while compiling u-boot on YOCTO

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I need help on creating a custom u-boot recipe for custom board.
I made a custom recipe for u-boot with our custom u-boot source and defconfig
While building iam getting the following error

```
ERROR: u-boot-cal-1.0-r1 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: u-boot-cal-1.0-r1 do_compile: Execution of '/media/calixto-systems/cal_linux/Sethu/yocto/yocto-secure/iec61850_module/iec61850_module3.1/build/tmp/work/iec61850_module-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-cal/1.0-r1/temp/run.do_compile.8827' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/calixto-systems/cal_linux/Sethu/yocto/yocto-secure/iec61850_module/iec61850_module3.1/build/tmp/work/iec61850_module-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-cal/1.0-r1/temp/log.do_compile.8827
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4
|   HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
| /bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
| make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:95: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 127
| make[1]: *** [Makefile:488: scripts_basic] Error 2
| make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
| make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
|   CFGCHK  u-boot.cfg
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/media/calixto-systems/cal_linux/Sethu/yocto/yocto-secure/iec61850_module/iec61850_module3.1/build/tmp/work/iec61850_module-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-cal/1.0-r1/temp/run.do_compile.8827' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Task (/media/calixto-systems/cal_linux/Sethu/yocto/yocto-secure/iec61850_module/iec61850_module3.1/meta-iec61850_module/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-cal.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 580 tasks of which 579 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /media/calixto-systems/cal_linux/Sethu/yocto/yocto-secure/iec61850_module/iec61850_module3.1/meta-iec61850_module/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-cal.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

What all things i have to consider while writing a u-boot recipe.

The below lines are my recipe for u-boot

```
DESCRIPTION = "u-boot bootloader for Calixto devices"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

#SRC_URI[md5sum] = "454a496b2ec8fa2cf60f6b2cba299b10"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

BRANCH ?= "2019.01"
UBOOT_GIT_PROTOCOL = "https"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SRC_URI = "git://sethucalixto@bitbucket.org/calixtolinuxplatform/calixto-am335x-uboot.git;protocol=${UBOOT_GIT_PROTOCOL};branch=${BRANCH}; \
           file://am335x_iec61850_module_defconfig"

DEPENDS += "dtc-native bc-native lzop-native flex-native bison-native python3-setuptools-native"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "iec61850-module"

SRCREV = "b96e9f6aed2c0a6cbf08c3f31b917694cc1f1b14"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the u-boot recipe in OE-Core. In particular you probably need the EXTRA_OEMAKE lines from u-boot.inc to setup the compiler/linker correctly.